# Is it possible to parse plain text as javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have code in github that I want to use in a bookmarklet, but if I reference it directly, it doesn't run as javascript. here is my code:
`javascript: var js = document.createElement('script'); js.src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SwiftSki/bookmarklet-game-prototype_1/master/bookmarklet.js"; document.body.appendChild(js);`

Is there any way to reference the code directly from github and have it run properly?
I would prefer to not use a cdn, because I would have to update the bookmarklet as I update the code.

Comment: No, and this is explicitely not intended. There was a service called RawGit in the past, but it's no longer operational, and [you can read here why](https://rawgit.com/).

Comment: Although, it seems there are new services by now, such as [raw.githack.com](https://raw.githack.com/). Still, you never know when they'll shut down.

Comment: ok, thanks. I tried githack in the past, and it didn't work too well.

Comment: I wonder if you could use AJAX or XmlHttpRequest to get the content of the response instead and render it as source code inside of the Script tag??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this will work. Uses `fetch()` and the `Function()` constructor. But as MDN points out executing JS source code from remote locations like this carries a lot of risk.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function

```js
fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SwiftSki/bookmarklet-game-prototype_1/master/bookmarklet.js')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.text()
  })
  .then((data) => {
    Function(data)()
  })
```

Comment: This works, but when I update the code, the script that runs does not update. When it is run now, it should display a second message stating the the page has been jQuerified. However, the second message does not appear.

Comment: So it looks the code you have written in your github repo is throwing an error which prevents the JS parser from getting to the second alert. `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (js:7), <anonymous>:4:15)
    at js:17`